# :termで改行がアウトプットに出力されない

Tags: vim

```
:term echo -e "hoge\\n\\n"
```

hogeより下の改行が削り取られてます。
何をしたらそのまんま改行もアウトプットされますでしょうか？

Comment: こちらで使用しているのは vim version 8.0.1144 なのですが、`:term echo -e "hoge\\n\\n"` の実行結果には改行が含まれています。しかし、`"`(ダブルクォート)も表示されてしまいます。そこで、ダブルクォートを入れないで `:term echo -e hoge\\n\\n` とすると質問文にあるのと同様に改行が削られてしまいます。vim のソースコードを眺めてみると、vim のコマンド入力行は単一行で継続行がなく、入力文字列の最後にある1個以上の連続した改行コード(`\n`)は無視されてしまう様です。なので、`:term echo -e "hoge\\n\\n "` などとする(ダブルクォートの直前にスペースを入れる)と、出力に改行が含まれる様になるかもしれません。

Comment: 最後にスペースを入れて乗り切ります。しかし、出力内容が削られる仕様は不便ですね。

Answer (score 1):

これはVimのバグですね。vim-jpにIssue登録してpatchを作成しました。
https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues/1200
問題なければtestを追加してvim_devに送信しようと思います。

Comment: 8.1.0522 で修正されました。https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f3aea59afa23304266dfd0dd26b5d8cc70a21331